# How to connect to a remote meteor mongodb using robomongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, remote-access, robo3t

I am using Meteor. Which is installed on another server.

I want to access its mongodb from another [Ubuntu Machine].

Now how can I access that mongodb via robomongo or any other tool?

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Robomongo in the upper left:

1. Click **create**
2. In the pop-up window enter the **address** and **port** of your Mongo server
3. Give the connection a name and click **save**.

Using the Terminal (on the client):

`mongo --host <hostname> --port <port>`

You have to make sure the port is not blocked on the Ubuntu machine running the Meteor application. Note: when developing a Meteor app the default Mongo port is `3001`.

Comment: On the client. (I'll add that to my answer for clarification)

Comment: I just ran this command: mongo --port 3001 --host 192.168.100.14. And it says:::    MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 192.168.100.14:3001/test
Thu Jan 21 19:18:42.489 Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.100.14:3001 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed

Comment: Are you sure the port is open on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Have you correctly configured your firewall? (i.e. if you use ufw, check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-open-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-linux-12-04-14-04-lts))

Comment: Here is my firewall stats:

root@myMachine:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----

3001/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3001                       ALLOW       Anywhere

3001/tcp                   ALLOW       192.168.100.14

3001/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)